# Dynamically altering the image source of a canvas object

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an animation that is ran on a timer along with some other animations. I would like to be able to change the images source file when an event is triggered but i am currently unable to access element.Source (element equaling the current canvas object which is a image).

```
public static void Clouds(Canvas canvas, int boundry)
{
    var random = new Random();
    foreach (FrameworkElement element in canvas.Children)
    {
        var elementName = Regex.Split(element.Name, "_");
        if (elementName[0] == "cloud")
        {
            if (Canvas.GetLeft(element) < canvas.ActualWidth + element.Width)
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(element, Canvas.GetLeft(element) + 1);
            } else
            {
                // Change image source file here.
                Canvas.SetTop(element, random.Next(0 - ((int)element.Height / 2), Core.GetPercentage((int)canvas.ActualHeight, boundry)));
                Canvas.SetLeft(element, 0 - element.Width);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: What type of element are you looking for in Canvas.Children?

Comment: all of the children are images, so just a image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because FrameworkElement has no property called Source, you have to cast or just pick the image elements you want.

Somthing like this may work

```
        public static void Clouds(Canvas canvas, int boundry)
        {
            var random = new Random();
            foreach (var image in canvas.Children.OfType<Image>())
            {
                if (image.Name.Contains("cloud_"))
                {
                    if (Canvas.GetLeft(image) < canvas.ActualWidth + image.Width)
                    {
                        Canvas.SetLeft(image, Canvas.GetLeft(image) + 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Canvas.SetTop(image, random.Next(0 - ((int)image.Height / 2), Core.GetPercentage((int)canvas.ActualHeight, boundry)));
                        Canvas.SetLeft(image, 0 - image.Width);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

now you will be able to access the source property as the var "image" is an Image